# How to implement "is typing" function in the friend list on IONIC 3?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a chat application that I am working on IONIC 3.19.0 and ANGULAR 5.0.3. But I am stuck on the implementation of "is typing" function in my friends list.

So, I want to make sure, when a friend is writing, that the "is typing" can be placed just that one.

But the opposite here at home, when a friend writes, the "is typing" poster for all the others at the same time.

I need solutions guys, I'm waiting for your answers.

Here are my codes :

**Chat.ts**

```
constructor(....) {

this.socket.connect();     
this.socket.on('update-typing', function (data) {
    if (data != null) {
      if (data.message == "typing") {
        this.typing = true;
      } else {
        this.typing = false;
      }
    }
}.bind(this)); }
```

**Chat.html**

```
<ion-content #content class="list-avatar-page"> 
 <ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let c of messageDetails; let i = index;let lst = last;let fst = first;" (click)="userClicked($event, c)">
  <ion-avatar item-start>
    <img src="{{c.avatar}}">
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2>{{c.username}}</h2>
  <h3 *ngIf="!typing">{{c.lastMessage}}</h3>
  <p *ngIf="typing">is typing...</p>
  <ion-note item-end>{{timeStamp(c.lastactivity)}}</ion-note>
</ion-item>
```

[Here is my friend list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCR83.png)

[Here is my friend list when writing to someone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uCW6.png)

Comment: You'd have to add the is typing stuff to messageDetails so it different per message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what we have here is a scope issue.

`this.typing` is the scope of your whole component.

What you want is to add a value to messageDetails.

Then you can do: `this.messageDetials[i].typing = true`
Where **i** is your id of that user.

Now in your template can do `*ngIf=c.typing`.

Comment: Thank you very much, your approach worked well and I did 3 days without finding a solution.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I just did that and pingo! It works !!!

**Chat.ts**

```
this.socket.connect();
this.socket.on('update-typing', function (data) {

  for (let index = 0; index < this.messageDetails.length; index++) {
    if (this.messageDetails[index].userid == data.userId) {
      if (data != null) {
        if (data.message == "typing") {
          this.messageDetails[index].istyping = true;
        } else {
          this.messageDetails[index].istyping = false;
        }
      }
    } else {
      this.messageDetails[index].istyping = false;
    }

  }

}.bind(this));
```

**Chat.html**

```
<ion-content #content class="list-avatar-page"> <ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let c of messageDetails; let i = index;" (click)="userClicked($event, c)">
  <ion-avatar item-start>
    <img src="{{c.avatar}}">
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2>{{c.username}}</h2>
  <h3 *ngIf="!c.istyping">{{c.lastMessage}}</h3>
  <p *ngIf="c.istyping">écrit...</p>
  <ion-note item-end>{{timeStamp(c.lastactivity)}}</ion-note>
</ion-item>
```

Thank you very much !